# Trouble with MAGMA in Python WSL?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello I'm setting up my computer because I need to use the library `deepqmc` for my thesis.

So I follow the steps that are in https://deepqmc.github.io/installation.html . And the tutorial in https://deepqmc.github.io/tutorial.html

And after everything is installed, although the  network is trainig and working, the following error appears:

`Error in magma_getdevice_arch: MAGMA not initialized (call magma_init() first) or bad device`

If anyone can explain to me what is happening and how can I solved it, I'll be very grateful.

Also I'm working on it with WSL, with direct Ubuntu the same error appears